# "was recommended" usage

Tags: word-usage, past-tense

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> "I was recommended to visit this restaurant"

Which kind of past tense is this?

Comment: If you are learning English, I recommend that you visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) for basic questions. You may also find it useful to view the [Tour of *this* site](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your sentence is grammatically correct.

Definition 1.2 of **recommend** as given in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recommend) is as follows (with selected usage examples):

> *[with object and infinitive]* Advise (someone) to do something:
>
> *‘you are strongly recommended to seek professional advice’*
> *‘Customers are recommended to consider these regional features when ordering.’*

Your sentence is in that format, except that it is in the simple past tense.

Comment: I take exception to the notion that this sentence is grammatical. The infinitive complement is messed upping it.

Comment: @tchrist I don't understand what you mean. And how is OP's sentence different from the dictionary example?

Comment: It’s not grammatical in America. It sounds completely bizarre to my ear, and mine is hardly alone; see Kate. It needs a “subjunctive” clause with *that*, not an infinitive one with *to*: *”Her mother recommended **that** she visit that restaurant”*.  You cannot recommend someone **to** do something in my language; you can only recommend **that** they do so.

Comment: @tchrist It sounds fine to me as a Brit. Are you saying that the dictionary is wrong?; or that I'm misinterpreting it? The [US version of the dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/recommend) has the same entry.

Comment: @tchrist So you **are** saying that you think the US dictionary I quoted is wrong?

Comment: **Dictionaries excel in documenting actual use,** whether by simple examples of their own or by referenced citations of written works. Unabridged dictionaries may include ‘markers of contemporaneity’ like *obsolete* or *archaic*, formality markers like *casual* or *coarse slang*, regional markers like *orig. U.S.* or *chiefly Brit.*, and on rare occasion ‘correctness’ markers like *catachrestic* or notes like *now considered incorrect*. Despite all that, **dictionaries never document *non*-use** because they cannot show that someone did *not* use something, let alone why they didn’t. (*cont.*)

Comment: (*cont.*) Indeed, they cannot do so. Because communities ᴅᴏ ɴᴏᴛ use constructions which that community considers ungrammatical, there is no record of it, and so community-specific unacceptability cannot be documented in the normal ways dictionaries document things. When I keep saying that it’s not grammatical ***“in my language”***, what I mean is that [my own *idiolect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiolect) cannot generate that construction. Evidence that others elsewhere and elsewhen ᴍᴀʏ be able to generate it [misses the point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignoratio_elenchi) I’m making.

Comment: I've got real problems with this one. I'd have no problems with ‘You are strongly recommended to seek professional advice.’ but consider that 'I was recommended to visit this restaurant.' sounds outlandish. I'd say the usage is in the process of becoming acceptable.

Comment: @tchrist 'It’s not grammatical in America' and 'It's not grammatical in my own idiolect' would be claimed to be totally synonymous by very few.

Comment: @tchrist (1) I fully accept that it may not be grammatical in your own idiolect. But that is *not* what you first said - and not what I was commenting on, because I'm not in a position to argue that. You first said "*It’s not grammatical in **America***." and that's what I was responding to. (*cont'd*)

Comment: (*cont'd*) (2) My understanding is that, in this forum, we generally take (reputable) dictionaries as definitive authorities - and, as you say, they document actual usage. Hence I thought it relevant to point out that this usage *is* documented as a (purported) example of AmE, apparently contradicting your *original* statement. And when you originally said that it's not grammatical '*in your **language***', I understood you to be referring to AmE in general - not specifically to your own **idiolect**.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for your contribution. I'm not good at grammatical analysis. Am I right in thinking that your two example sentences are ‘*You are strongly recommended to seek professional advice.*’ and '*I was recommended to visit this restaurant.*' are grammatically 'equivalent'/similar (except for tense)?

Comment: Arguably. But 'You are strongly recommended to' has arguably become a unitary expression. Some idioms are labelled 'extragrammatical' by some authors, indicating that though acceptable (being idioms), they are considered to push back the boundaries of standard grammar.

Answer (score 0):

It's the past simple in the passive voice. However, it doesn't work with the verb 'to recommend', because 'recommend' is transitive - which means it needs an object. eg: 'He recommended that restaurant to us'.

'This restaurant was recommended to me', is correct, because the object, 'restaurant' is now placed in the subject position, and now the passive voice can be used properly.

Comment: -1 I disagree - see my answer.

Comment: I partially disagree, but must downvote for lack of corroborative references (in fact, TrevorD gives an authority claiming this answer is incorrect).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out - I'll make a note of it in future.